# Passing params to sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, in my rails app I developed a search filter where I am using sliders. For example, I want to show orders where the price is between **min** value and **max** value which comes from the slider in params. I have column in my db called "price" and params[:priceMin], params[:priceMax]. So I can't write something kinda `MyModel.where(params)...`. You may say, that I should do something like `MyModel.where('price >= ? AND price <= ?', params[:priceMin], params[:priceMax])` but there is a problem: the number of search criteria depends on user desire, so I don't know the size of params hash that passes to query. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

I've already done it this way

```
def query_senders
query = ""
if params.has_key?(:place_from)
  query += query_and(query) + "place_from='#{params[:place_from]}'"
end
if params.has_key?(:expected_price_min) and params.has_key?(:expected_price_max)
      query += query_and(query) + "price >= '#{params[:expected_price_min]}' AND price <= '#{params[:expected_price_max]}'"
end...
```

but according to ruby guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) this approach is bad because of SQL injection danger.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#limit-and-offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size of params hash by doing `params.count`. By the way you described it, it still seems that you will know what parameters *can* be passed by the user. So just check whether they're present, and split the query accordingly.

Edited:

```
def query_string
  return = {}
  if params[:whatever].present?
     return.merge({whatever: #{params[:whatever]}}"
  elsif ...
end
```

The above would form a hash for all of the exact values you're searching for, avoiding SQL injection. Then for such filters as prices you can just check whether the values are in correct format (numbers only) and only perform if so.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yep, this method is the first to come to mind, but it is not good because of SQL injection danger. It is explained in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Well, you can just pass a hash to get the same result then. I'll update the answer.